# Autohotkey script to launch program on internet reconnection

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, autohotkey

I'm trying to code a script that monitors the internet, and if it disconnects to run chrome.exe on **reconnection**.

Here is what I have so far;

```
UrlDownloadToVar(URL) {
ComObjError(false)
WebRequest := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
WebRequest.Open("GET", URL)
WebRequest.Send()
Return WebRequest.ResponseText
}

#Persistent
SetTimer, CheckInternet, 100
Return

CheckInternet:
html := UrlDownloadToVar("http://www.google.com")
if html
    {}
else
    {
    MsgBox,, Internet status, not working will check again later, 1
    sleep, 20000
    if html
        {
        MsgBox,, Internet status, 2nd  check = working, 5
        Run chrome.exe
        }
    }
```

The issues are:

- The MsgBox showing internet disconnection doesn't appear straight away when the internet
  disconnects, it takes like 6-7 seconds
- Msgbox confirming reconnection & Chrome.exe are not launched when the internet returns (and the internet has definitely returned, and
  within 20000 milliseconds - I've manually tested this)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are doing `UrlDownloadToVar` only once. You need to retest by redoing it before checking again the content of the `html` var.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek  That was exactly the problem. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-run `html := UrlDownloadToVar("http://www.google.com")` before the second check to update that variable.

I think it would be better to run a while loop. This way if the Internet connection doesn't return, it will keep waiting. This way you can check on shorter intervals and have the script respond more promptly.

```
html := UrlDownloadToVar("http://www.google.com")
while(!html) {
    MsgBox,, Internet status, not working will check again later, 1
    sleep, 20000
    html := UrlDownloadToVar("http://www.google.com")
}
MsgBox,, Internet status, 2nd  check = working, 5
    Run chrome.exe
}
```

If you only want to pop up the message once, you could put that into an `if(!html) {}` before the while statement.